# How to stop Google Chrome to be installed on my Computer?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, adware

i have found that i had a adware installed on my Windows 8.1 PC that keep installing either Opera or Chrome, i managed to remove it so never mind that, but Chrome keep being installed every one hour of season (which means: for every hour that i use the PC), so what i want is to prevent Chrome to be installed on my PC forever, also preventing "our sponsors" from make a pack installing when i install a freeware.

to put simply: prevent Google Chrome being installed on this PC for it's lifespan

Comment: the real issue here is the malware. get rid of the malware, and the chrome problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is still installed once every hour, you certainly didn't get rid of the adware/malware on your computer.

So you should solve that problem first.

About Chrome itself:

Chrome is software that doesn't require administrative rights to be installed, thus making it harder to prevent it from being installed. But as far as I remember, it installs into a specific directory inside the user's home directory.

What you can try is:

- Make sure UAC is enabled
- Make sure the user is not an administrator
- Deny Write-Access to that `Chrome` directory to the user

Installation should fail.

Comment: that solves one of the problems, any idea of how do i remove that malware, if you feel kindly enough to?

Comment: Have you seen the link in David's comment, that's a good starting point.